# Directive in directive template with ng-repeat and attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is an interesting question and situation I find myself in.  This is a little complex to explain/copy into Stack Overflow so here is a Plunker for your consideration: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zs8AXh6KZvTAqeBFFAK0

## The issue

The issue is that I am trying to pass an attribute value from a one directive to another directive inside the first directives template.

If you take a look at `template.html` in the Plunker example you will see the problem.  The `example` directive gets a value from `ng-repeat` in this case `thing`.  `thing` is an attribute value on the directive in the `index.html` which is used in the `example` directive in it's isolate scope.  I assumed that once it had that value it could pass it to children directives that reside in the `example` template.  This doesn't seem to be the case as I get `undefined` when alerting the value.

## What could be the problem

You will notice that the directives both have isolate scope which I am assuming could cause an issue somewhere.

## What I've Tried

I am have tried all sorts of different combinations with `=`, `@` and `&` to get this to work properly and everything was a no go.  Still just got undefined each time.

I've even tried passing the value differently using curly braces and not.  Each time seems not to work.

I think at one point I did attempt using `$attrs.$observe` and I think this worked but I felt like this was unnecessary.  The Angular IRC suggested I should only be using this as a "last resort".  I don't feel like I am quite there yet.

## Question(s)

Why isn't this working the way I am expecting it to?  Is this even a thing you should do in Angular?  Am I going about this the wrong way?  If so, what's the correct approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misspelled the directive's attribute:

```
somethingelse
```

instead of

```
 somethingElse
```

You know that the attributes in the directives are case sensitive and you write them with a camel case notation while in the html it is case insensitive.

Here is the updated plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/QGS9yLpggAWuBg9Ytmp7?p=preview

Comment: This wasn't the answer I was looking for, but hey it works!  This is a deeper issue I am dealing with outside of a typo.  Instead of deleting this question altogether I wanted to give you the upvote and checkmark.